# How to run queue in laravel 5.5 without shell or ssh?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-queue

i have hosted my laravel application on shared hosting where server does not allow me for ssh or shell access. And created the some events in my application and i have queued that events now i am unable to process queues.

So, please guide me the way to process queue.

Comment: Maybe cron job.

Comment: You really need to get rid of the shared hosting, especially when you make use of the more advanced laravel features like running jobs. You need to be able to monitor the jobs, eg with supervisord. Non shared hosting is so cheap nowadays. It'll save you time and money to change now.